# requests and lxml - login and scrape data - no content shows up

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, python-requests, lxml

I am able to successfully login and get a 200 status response. However, when I try to use lxml to scape data there is nothing inside the main HTML tag:

```
<main role="main" sp-main></main>
```

If I login via browser all the content along with the data I'm trying to pull is inside of `main`, it does take a while for the content to be loaded, maybe 5 seconds or so. I did try setting a time.sleep(x) before pulling in the dashboard content, but still nothing is populated in main when I pull it with the script.

(A lot more content gets loaded, just didn't want to paste it all)

```
<main role="main" sp-main=""><button class="sp-fixed-btn sp-feedback" ui-sref="feedback"
            ng-show="isAuthenticated &amp;&amp; !kiosk">
            <div class="icon-chat-outline"></div>
            <div translate="CHROME_FEEDBACK">feedback</div>
        </button> <button class="sp-fixed-btn sp-help" ui-sref="help" ng-hide="kiosk">
            <div class="icon-question"></div>
            <div translate="CHROME_GETHELP">help</div>
        </button>
        <div class="sp-view sp-view-on" ng-class="{ 'sp-view-on': isAuthenticated }">
            <div class="sp-loader animate-loader" ng-class="{ 'animate-loader': !showLoader }">
                <div class="sp-loader-dots searching-ellipsis remove-dots" ng-class="{ 'remove-dots': !showLoader }">
                    <span>•</span> <span>•</span> <span>•</span></div>
                <!---->
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div ui-view="" class="sp-animate">
                <article page-spinner="dashboard">
                    <div class="sp-dash-container" style="width: 965px;">
                        <!---->
                        <div class="sp-widget-item">
                            <div sp-current-production-gauge="">
                                <sp-widget-container heading="CURRENT_PRODUCTION" show-menu="true"
                                    widgetcolor="#d9dbdc">
                                    <!---->
                                    <div class="widget-status-bar" ng-if="!!widgetColor"
                                        ng-style="{'background': widgetColor}" style="background: rgb(217, 219, 220);">
                                    </div>
                                    <!---->
                                    <div class="widget-with-header">
                                        <div class="widget-content" ng-mouseleave="showOptions=false">
                                            <div class="sp-widget-header-container"
                                                ng-class="{'make-blue': showOptions}" ng-show="showHeader">
                                                <h5 class="sp-title" translate="CURRENT_PRODUCTION"
                                                    ng-class="{'make-white': showOptions}">Current Power</h5>
                                                <!---->
                                                <div class="sp-dots" id="sp-dots"
                                                    ng-hide="showOptions || showMenu!=='true'"
                                                    ng-click="showOptions=true"><span>•</span> <span>•</span>
                                                    <span>•</span></div>
                                                <div class="sp-widget-header-icons ng-hide" ng-show="showOptions">
                                                    <div class="sp-widget-title-contents"><span
                                                            class="widget-settings-icons icon-info" title="info"
                                                            ng-click="showCurrentPowerHelpModal()"></span></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <hr class="sp-settings-title-hr" ng-class="{'hide-title-hr': showOptions}">
                                            <div class="sp-widget-body" ng-show="showBody">
                                                <div class="sp-widget-body-contents"><button
                                                        analytics-category="Dashboard"
                                                        analytics-event="Click_On_Current_Power" analytics-on="click"
                                                        class="sp-dash-btn" ng-click="goPage('graphs', true)"></button>
                                                    <div class="sp-dash-item-subtitle">
                                                        <div class="sp-dash-description" translate="NOW_PRODUCING">Now
                                                            Producing</div>
                                                        <div class="sp-dash-value">2.1 kW</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="now_prod_chart" style="overflow: hidden;"
                                                        data-highcharts-chart="5">
                                                        <div id="highcharts-opo2oxr-57" dir="ltr"
                                                            class="highcharts-container "
                                                            style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 300px; height: 170px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif;">
                                                            <svg version="1.1" class="highcharts-root"
                                                                style="font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-size:12px;"
                                                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300"
                                                                height="170" viewBox="0 0 300 170">
                                                                <desc>Created with Highcharts 7.1.2</desc>
                                                                <defs>
                                                                    <clipPath id="highcharts-opo2oxr-59-">
                                                                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="170"
                                                                            fill="none"></rect>
                                                                    </clipPath>
                                                                </defs>
                                                                <rect fill="transparent" class="highcharts-background"
                                                                    x="0" y="0" width="300" height="170" rx="0" ry="0">
                                                                </rect>
                                                                <rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-background"
                                                                    x="0" y="20" width="300" height="170"></rect>
                                                                <g class="highcharts-pane-group" data-z-index="0">
                                                                    <path fill="transparent"
                                                                        d="M 77.75 147.5 A 72.25 72.25 0 0 1 222.249963875003 147.42775001204166 L 207.7999711000024 147.44220000963332 A 57.8 57.8 0 0 0 92.2 147.5 Z"
                                                                        class="highcharts-pane " stroke="#cccccc"
                                                                        stroke-width="1"></path>
                                                                </g>
                                                                <g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid"
                                                                    data-z-index="1">
                                                                    <path fill="none" data-z-index="1"
                                                                        class="highcharts-grid-line"
                                                                        d="M 150 147.5 L 77.75 147.5" opacity="1">
                                                                    </path>
                                                                    <path fill="none" data-z-index="1"
                                                                        class="highcharts-grid-line"
                                                                        d="M 150 147.5 L 98.91153505927196 96.41153505927194"
                                                                        opacity="1"></path>
                                                                    <path fill="none" data-z-index="1"
                                                                        class="highcharts-grid-line"
                                                                        d="M 150 147.5 L 150 75.25" opacity="1"></path>
                                                                    <path fill="none" data-z-index="1"
                                                                        class="highcharts-grid-line"
                                                                        d="M 150 147.5 L 201.08846494072804 96.41153505927196"
                                                                        opacity="1"></path>
                                                                    <path fill="none" data-z-index="1"
                                                                        class="highcharts-grid-line"
                                                                        d="M 150 147.5 L 222.25 147.5" opacity="1">
                                                                    </path>
                                                                </g>
                                                                <rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-border"
                                                                    data-z-index="1" x="0" y="20" width="300"
                                                                    height="170"></rect>
                                                                <g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-yaxis"
                                                                    data-z-index="2">
                                                                    <path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick"
                                                                        stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1"
                                                                        d="M 77.75 147.5 L 67.75 147.5" opacity="1">
                                                                    </path>
                                                                    <path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick"
                                                                        stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1"
                                                                        d="M 98.91153505927196 96.41153505927194 L 91.84046724740648 89.34046724740647"
                                                                        opacity="1"></path>
                                                                    <path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick"
                                                                        stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1"
                                                                        d="M 150 75.25 L 150 65.25" opacity="1"></path>
                                                                    <path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick"
                                                                        stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1"
                                                                        d="M 201.08846494072804 96.41153505927196 L 208.15953275259352 89.34046724740648"
                                                                        opacity="1"></path>
                                                                    <path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick"
                                                                        stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1"
                                                                        d="M 222.25 147.5 L 232.25 147.5" opacity="1">
                                                                    </path>
                                                                    <path fill="none" class="highcharts-axis-line"
                                                                        data-z-index="7"
                                                                        d="M 77.75 147.5 A 72.25 72.25 0 0 1 222.249963875003 147.42775001204166 M 150 147.5 A 0 0 0 0 0 150 147.5 ">
                                                                    </path>
                                                                </g>
                                                                <g data-z-index="2"
                                                                    class="highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-0 highcharts-solidgauge-series  highcharts-tracker"
                                                                    transform="translate(0,20) scale(1 1)">
                                                                    <g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 highcharts-tracker"
                                                                        data-z-index="1" transform="translate(106,138)">
                                                                    </g>
                                                                </g>
                                                                <g class="highcharts-series-group" data-z-index="3">
                                                                    <g data-z-index="0.1"
                                                                        class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-solidgauge-series  highcharts-tracker"
                                                                        transform="translate(0,20) scale(1 1)"
                                                                        clip-path="url(https://monitor.us.sunpower.com/#highcharts-opo2oxr-59-)">
                                                                        <path fill="rgb(105,179,66)"
                                                                            d="M 77.75 127.49999999999999 A 72.25 72.25 0 0 1 130.4281223771638 57.95142628121894 L 134.34249790173104 71.86114102497515 A 57.8 57.8 0 0 0 92.2 127.5 Z"
                                                                            sweep-flag="0" stroke-linecap="round"
                                                                            stroke-linejoin="round"
                                                                            class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-0">
                                                                        </path>
                                                                    </g>
                                                                    <g data-z-index="0.1"
                                                                        class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-solidgauge-series "
                                                                        transform="translate(0,20) scale(1 1)"
                                                                        clip-path="none"></g>
                                                                </g><text x="150" text-anchor="middle"
                                                                    class="highcharts-title" data-z-index="4"
                                                                    style="color:#333333;font-size:18px;fill:#333333;"
                                                                    y="34"></text><text x="150" text-anchor="middle"
                                                                    class="highcharts-subtitle" data-z-index="4"
                                                                    style="color:#666666;fill:#666666;" y="34"></text>
                                                                <g class="highcharts-legend" data-z-index="7">
                                                                    <rect fill="none" class="highcharts-legend-box"
                                                                        rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8"
                                                                        visibility="hidden"></rect>
                                                                    <g data-z-index="1">
                                                                        <g></g>
                                                                    </g>
                                                                </g>
                                                                <g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels"
                                                                    data-z-index="7"></g>
                                                            </svg>
                                                            <div class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels"
                                                                style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                                                                <span opacity="1"
                                                                    style="position: absolute; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 0.9rem; white-space: nowrap; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 25.75px; top: 137.5px; color: rgb(94, 99, 103); cursor: default; text-align: center; transform: rotate(0deg); transform-origin: 50% 12px; text-overflow: clip; opacity: 1;">
                                                                    <div>0 kW</div>
                                                                </span><span opacity="1"
                                                                    style="position: absolute; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 0.9rem; white-space: nowrap; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 53.1273px; top: 58.1273px; color: rgb(94, 99, 103); cursor: default; text-align: center; transform: rotate(0deg); transform-origin: 50% 12px; text-overflow: clip; opacity: 1;">
                                                                    <div>1.3 kW</div>
                                                                </span><span opacity="1"
                                                                    style="position: absolute; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 0.9rem; white-space: nowrap; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 132.5px; top: 25.25px; color: rgb(94, 99, 103); cursor: default; text-align: center; transform: rotate(0deg); transform-origin: 50% 12px; text-overflow: clip; opacity: 1;">
                                                                    <div>2.5 kW</div>
                                                                </span><span opacity="1"
                                                                    style="position: absolute; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 0.9rem; white-space: nowrap; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 211.873px; top: 58.1273px; color: rgb(94, 99, 103); cursor: default; text-align: center; transform: rotate(0deg); transform-origin: 50% 12px; text-overflow: clip; opacity: 1;">
                                                                    <div>3.8 kW</div>
                                                                </span><span opacity="1"
                                                                    style="position: absolute; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 0.9rem; white-space: nowrap; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 250.25px; top: 137.5px; color: rgb(94, 99, 103); cursor: default; text-align: center; transform: rotate(0deg); transform-origin: 50% 12px; text-overflow: clip; opacity: 1;">
                                                                    <div>5 kW</div>
                                                                </span></div>
                                                            <div class="highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-0 highcharts-solidgauge-series  highcharts-tracker"
                                                                style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 20px; opacity: 1; visibility: inherit;">
                                                                <div class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 highcharts-tracker"
                                                                    style="position: absolute; left: 106px; top: 138px; opacity: 1;">
                                                                    <span data-z-index="1"
                                                                        style="position: absolute; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; white-space: nowrap; font-weight: 600; color: transparent; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 5px; top: 5px;">
                                                                        <div class="production-label">2.065 kW</div>
                                                                    </span></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </sp-widget-container>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!---->
                        <div class="sp-widget-item sp-energy-mix" ng-if="homeConsumptionUser"
                            style="top: 0px; left: 325px;">
                            <sp-energy-mix id="energy_mix_landscape" show-heading="true" set-dates="day">
                                <sp-widget-container heading="TODAY_ENERGY_MIX" show-menu="true" widgetcolor="#d9dbdc">
                                    <!---->
                                    <div class="widget-status-bar" ng-if="!!widgetColor"
                                        ng-style="{'background': widgetColor}" style="background: rgb(217, 219, 220);">
                                    </div>
                                    <!---->
                                    <div class="widget-with-header">
                                        <div class="widget-content" ng-mouseleave="showOptions=false">
                                            <div class="sp-widget-header-container"
                                                ng-class="{'make-blue': showOptions}" ng-show="showHeader">
                                                <h5 class="sp-title" translate="TODAY_ENERGY_MIX"
                                                    ng-class="{'make-white': showOptions}">Today's Energy Mix</h5>
                                                <!---->
                                                <div class="sp-dots" id="sp-dots"
                                                    ng-hide="showOptions || showMenu!=='true'"
                                                    ng-click="showOptions=true"><span>•</span> <span>•</span>
                                                    <span>•</span></div>
                                                <div class="sp-widget-header-icons ng-hide" ng-show="showOptions">
                                                    <div class="sp-widget-title-contents"><span
                                                            class="widget-settings-icons icon-info" title="info"
                                                            ng-click="showEnergyMixHelpModal()"></span></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <hr class="sp-settings-title-hr" ng-class="{'hide-title-hr': showOptions}">
                                            <div class="sp-widget-body" ng-show="showBody">
                                                <div class="sp-widget-body-contents"><button
                                                        analytics-category="Dashboard"
                                                        analytics-event="Click_On_Energy_Mix" analytics-on="click"
                                                        class="sp-dash-btn" ng-click="goPage('graphs')"></button>
                                                    
                                                       
    </main>
```

Here is my script:

```
import requests
import lxml
import time
from lxml import html


cookies = {
    '_ga': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://monitor.us.sunpower.com/',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'If-Modified-Since': 'Mon, 06 Jul 2020 20:10:01 GMT',
    'Origin': 'https://monitor.us.sunpower.com',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'authority': 'elhapi.edp.sunpower.com',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'access-control-request-method': 'GET',
    'access-control-request-headers': 'authorization',
    'origin': 'https://monitor.us.sunpower.com',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://monitor.us.sunpower.com/',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'authorization': 'SP-CUSTOM 9c0f119d-685f-463c-812c-e03dd6a99b84',
}

data = '{"username":"user@email.com","password":"xxxxxxxxxxx","isPersistent":false}'

response = requests.post('https://monitor.us.sunpower.com/', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
    
login_url = "https://elhapi.edp.sunpower.com/v1/elh/authenticate"

s = requests.Session()
response = s.post(login_url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(response)


url = "https://monitor.us.sunpower.com/#!/dashboard/"

result = s.get(
    url, 
    headers = dict(referer = url)
)
    
tree = html.fromstring(result.content)

lxml.html.open_in_browser(tree)
```

any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: That means the website is using javascript for loading data. Use `selenium` for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @bigbounty commented you should use Selenium for this. The content is being loaded with javascript so it does not appear with simple html request.

Before using Selenium you will have to install a webdriver and configure it. There are plenty of tutorials online that show how to do that such as this one:
http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations-2018/classes/selenium/selenium-windows-install/

```
session = requests.Session()
response = session.post(login_url, data=data, headers=headers)

# you may have to specify your webdriver path depending on how you installed it
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') # or '-start maximized' to see the window open

# create a webdriver object
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# loads the cookies from the session on to the driver
for c in session.cookies :
    driver.add_cookie({'name': c.name, 'value': c.value, 'path': c.path, 'expiry': c.expires})

# get the url with the driver
driver.get(yourURL)
html = driver.page_source  # downloads the html including the html loaded with javascript
```

Comment: I got the chromedriver installed. I just don't know how to use it within the request.Session()

Comment: You can try opening the selenium page and loading the cookies from your requests session. You can access the cookies from any request with r.cookies or in your case since you are using a session you can do session.cookies.get_dict(). Then you can load those cookies in selenium.

Comment: I updated my answer above to give an example of how you would load session cookies in Selenium. I hope this helps.